# Preview changes that would be added by a merge when there are multiple merge bases

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I'm at commit `F` on branch `main` and I'd like to review the changes from branch `topic-2`:

[image: Commit graph produced by the shell script at the end of the question.]

*See the script below on how this commit history was produced exactly. Each change that is not a merge adds one empty file, so that I can easily demonstrate which changes come from which commit.*

The only change that has not yet been added to `main` is `D`, but doing a simple `git diff --stat ...topic-2` shows 2 changes:

```
warning: HEAD...topic-2: multiple merge bases, using 1651defc16ef2a5c0129ee3806dca7881f138407
 C | 0
 D | 0
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

*I'm using `--stat` for brevity, I'm actually interested in the full diffs throughout this question.*

The reason for this is simple to understand. `git diff` found 2 merge bases it could use to produce a diff against `topic-2` and chose commit `B`. Diffing `B` and `E` will show changes from `C` and `D`. But if I then merge `topic-2` into `main` and show the merge commit, I will see that actually only change `D` was added to `main`:

```
commit f0f9fba1c262017f9cc1ffa213d211529d9a7351 (HEAD -> main, tag: G)
Merge: b95f9e8 2d97842
Author: [...]
Date:   2023-07-20 11:46:38 +0200

    Merge branch 'topic-2'

 D | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

**Is there a way to produce this list of changes (i.e. only showing changes from `D` in this example) without performing the merge?**

I know that I could also merge the current state of `main` into `topic-2` before running `git diff`, but I would like to skip that step.

I also know that producing the diff I'm looking for is not always possible mechanically, because it involves doing a merge internally in one way or another, which could produce conflicts, but it'd be nice to get that diff in one step from the CLI in the 95% of cases where there isn't a conflict.

---

The script used to produce the commit history above and produce the diff and merge shown above.

```bash
rm -rf foo
git init foo

change() { touch $1; git add -A; git commit -q -m $1; git tag $1; }
merge() { git merge -q --no-ff $1; git tag $2; }

(
    cd foo
    change A

    git checkout -b topic-1 main
    change B

    git checkout main
    change C

    git checkout -b topic-2 main
    change D
    merge topic-1 E

    git checkout main
    merge topic-1 F

    echo '====='
    git --no-pager diff --stat ...topic-2
    echo '====='

    merge topic-2 G
    echo '====='
    git --no-pager show --stat
    echo '====='
)
```